# read multiple netcdf files in fortran using openmp

Tags: fortran, openmp, netcdf4

I have two netcdf files - ocean_rst_01.nc and ocean_rst_02.nc - which I wish to read in parallel using openmp in Fortran. The code I am using is the following

```
   implicit none
   ....
   ....

   !$OMP THREADPRIVATE(ncid,varid)
     write ( *, '(a,i8)' ) &
  '  The number of processors available = ', omp_get_num_procs ( )
     write ( *, '(a,i8)' ) &
  '  The number of threads available    = ', omp_get_max_threads ( )
   filen = "ocean_rst_0x"
   !$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(j,filename,varname,buf) 
   do i = 1, nbv
      j = OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
      print*,"i=",i, "j = ",j! OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
      if (i<10) write(num,"(a11,i1)") filen,i
      if (i>=10) write(num,"(a10,i2)") filen,i
      filename(i)=trim(num)//".nc"
      write(6,*) "Reading file = ",trim(filename(i))," by ", j
      varname="CHLA"

      call check( NF90_OPEN(trim(filename(i)),NF90_NOWRITE,ncid) )
      call check( NF90_INQ_VARID(ncid,trim(varname),varid) )
      start = (/1, 1, 1/)
      count = (/nlon, nlat, nlev/)
      call check( NF90_GET_VAR(ncid,varid,buf,start=start, &
       count = count) )
      call check( NF90_CLOSE(ncid))

      call check( NF90_OPEN(trim(filename(i)),NF90_NOWRITE,ncid) )
      call check( NF90_INQ_VARID(ncid,"zeta",varid) )
      start_1 = (/1, 1/)
      count_1 = (/nlon, nlat/)
      call check( NF90_GET_VAR(ncid,varid,buf2d,start=start_1, &
       count = count_1) )
      call check( NF90_CLOSE(ncid))

      var(:,:,:,i) = buf(:,:,:)
      var2d(:,:,i) = buf2d(:,:)
      write(6,*) "var = ",var(132,231,39,i), "read by thread = ",j
      write(6,*) "zeta = ",var2d(132,231,i), "read by thread = ",j
   enddo
   !$OMP END PARALLEL DO

  end
```

I am compiling the code in a CRAY machine using ftn and netcdf4 libraries.

I am getting random outputs. Sometimes I get the right output. Sometimes the output of var2d and/or var is same for both the threads. And if I declare buf2d as private, I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) error. And Sometimes I get the followong error

a.out: posixio.c:442: px_rel: Assertion `pxp->bf_offset <= offset && offset < pxp->bf_offset + (off_t) pxp->bf_extent' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

The above algorithm works fine if I read multiple ascii files. What is the right way to read multiple **netcdf files in fortran 90  using openmp** ?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. USE tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Fortran 90 is just one old version.

Comment: What is `num`? Where does it come from? Please declare all your variables, see [mcve].

Comment: Do you know for sure that netcdf is thread safe, and if it is it has been compiled in a thread safe manner?

Comment: `netCDF`is not thread safe except for the java interface.  https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/faq.html and https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/support/help/MailArchives/netcdf/msg13578.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately netcdf is not thread-safe currently, see for instance

https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/support/help/MailArchives/netcdf/msg13578.html

though people do seem to be thinking about making it so, for instance

https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/blogs/developer/entry/implementing-thread-safe-access-to

Thus what you want to do is unlikely to work, and if it does it may not work reliably, as the actions of one thread will "interfere" with those of another.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. I have now abandoned this approach and moved to mpi. It works with mpi.

Comment: @aryapaul do you have some examples on how to use mpi with nf90_open?